# Connect to a postgres running internally within a cluster through a kubernetes pod

Tags: linux, networking, kubernetes, port-forwarding, ip-routing

I've got a kubernetes pod `myapp-2390458f-kfjgd` I can get access to with `kubectl` and an instance of a `PostgreSQL` that can be accessed from within the kubernetes cluster by the name `mypos.tgres.com`, but it cannot be accessed outside of the cluster.

I'm trying to connect to the `PostgreSQL` from my laptop, but to my knowledge `kubectl port-forward` would not work in that case since I can only forward my local port to some pod's port. But it would not forward traffic further to `mypos.tgres.com`.

Is there a way to forward all traffic to the actual db instance `mypos.tgres.com` from the pod that can be accessed from my laptop?

What would be the possible solution?

The `PostgreSQL` is not running as a pod, but on an internal network that is only accessible from the Kubernetes cluster's pods. The Kubernetes cluster is hosted in our own infrastracture, not in a cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Pod that acts as a proxy to the internal Postgres service; then you can `kubectl port-forward` to that Pod to get access to Postgres from your laptop.

We can set up a simple proxy like this:

```
kubectl run postgres-proxy \
  --image docker.io/alpine/socat \
  -- \
  tcp-listen:5432,fork,reuseaddr \
  tcp-connect:mypos.tgres.com:5432
```

Now you can expose that proxy on your local machine:

```
kubectl port-forward pod/postgres-proxy 5432:5432
```

And then access postgres via your local machine:

```
psql -h localhost ...
```

Delete the proxy pod when you're done:

```
kubectl delete pod/postgres-proxy
```